# Vuetify input field graphical glitch (name is striked)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a strange display problem on an input field using vuetify (image below).

Do you have an idea on the root cause and how to avoid this?

[image]

Here is the way I use it:

```
<v-form>
    <v-text-field 
        v-for="p in visibleParameters" 
        :key="p.id" 
        :label="p.title ? p.title : p.name"
        :placeholder="placeholder(p.data_type)"
        v-model="valuesModel.params[p.name]" 
        outlined="true">
    </v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

Comment: Please, provide more informations like your code, Vue & Vuetify version. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @federico-dondi thanks a lot for your comment. I added a code snippet to show how I use it. "vue": "^2.6.10", "vuetify": "^2.2.0".